# Parsing a cell by a delimiter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

In a column I have several cells containing dates range, they look like so:

```
DD.MM-DD.MM
eg: 05.09-27.09
```

I'm not sure of what would be the best way to extract here `05` and `27`.
I thought first about two but I didn't manage to properly implementing them:

- using `FIND` with `-` (delimiter), and `LEFT` to get `05.09`. Then another `FIND` with `.`?
- doing a `FIND` on '.' take the left part with `LEFT`, then how can I reach the the second occurence of `.` and take the value on it's left again with `LEFT`?

If you have any recommendation on how to implement one of those idea or if you come up with something better, I take it.

Thanks.

Comment: You're on the right track. If you can say whether the string will ALWAYS be `aa.bb-cc.dd`. If it is, then you use either method equally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overthink this. If the format is always `xx.yy-aa.bb` you can simply get the characters by their position

- `=left(A1,5)` gives you xx.yy
- `=right(A1,5)` gives you aa.bb

You only want the days, not the months, you can still use the absolute positions.

- `=left(A1,2)` for xx
- `=mid(A1,7,2)` for aa